# Array of pointers data structure

Tags: c++, vectors

Does this data structure make sense? It's essentially a vector of pointers, intended to point to larger objects. In effect, it gives the benefit of a linked list, with an \$O(1)\$ lookup at the cost of maintaining an array of pointers to each element.

What edge cases am I missing, and what's the formal name of this data structure? (What's the standard data structure used in such situations?)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class pointerArray
{

    vector<void*> addresses;
    public:
    pointerArray(int initialSize=100)
    {
        addresses.resize(initialSize);
    }
    ~pointerArray()
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++)
        {
            if(addresses[i]!=0)
            {
                delete (T*)addresses[i];
            }
        }
    }
    T& operator[](unsigned int pos)
    {
        if(pos >= addresses.capacity())
        {
            addresses.resize(pos*2);
        }
        if(addresses[pos] == 0)
        {
            T* ptr = new T;
            addresses[pos] = ptr;
        }
        return *(T*)(addresses[pos]);

    }
};


int main()
{
    pointerArray<string> pa(100);
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        pa[i]="Hello World This Is a Very Long String";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        cout<<pa[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. How is this data structure superior to `std::vector<T*>` or (better) `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`? Indeed, isn't it exactly the same thing as these standard library features? And shouldn't one prefer standard library implementations of common data structures over reinventing the wheel (unless the standard implementation has unacceptable performance, like `std::map`)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this data structure has any special name(vector of pointers sounds reasonable).

Now about the code itself:

1. I do not see any reason to use `void*` pointers here and cast them explicitly every time you access an element. You can just use `vector<T*> addresses` and get rid of all casts. You can also use smart pointers(`unique_ptr` looks like a good choice here). Here is my version of this class:

   ```
   template<class T>
   class PointerArray {
   public:
       PointerArray(size_t initialSize = 100): array(initialSize) {}

       T& operator[](size_t pos) {
           if (pos >= array.size()) {
               size_t newSize = std::max(pos + 1, 2 * pos);
               array.resize(newSize);
           }
           if (!array[pos]) {
               array[pos] = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()); // or std::make_unique in C++14
           } 
           return *array[pos];
       }

   private:
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> array;
   };
   ```

   There no need for a custom destructor anymore(`unique_ptr` handles it).
   Note that I have added this line: `int newSize = std::max(pos + 1, 2 * pos);`. Why is it necessary? We need it when the `initialSize` is `0` and so is `pos`.
2. In this line: `if(pos >= addresses.capacity())`, you should be comparing `pos` to the vector's size, not capacity(because it is an undefined behavior to access elements of the vector beyond size).
3. More general notes:

   - `using namespace std;` is a bad practice. There is no need to pollute global namespace.
   - Binary operators are usually surrounded with whitespaces. It is also conventional to have an empty line between different functions to improve readability.
4. And the last one: do have good reasons to use this data structure? In my opinion, as long as a simple `std::vector<T>` works fine, there is no need to invent any new data structures.

Comment: Whats the name of the syntax you used in the default constructor?  This was more of a thought than anything else, such a data structure gets rid of the requirement to have a large contiguous memory block when dealing with larger objects in memory

Comment: @Akash It is called member initializer list: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what kraskevich said (especially about smart pointers), I would also implement a proper copy constructor and assignment operator (or explicitly delete them).

Your current version would produce a shallow copy (and as a result UB when deleting referenced objects a second time). Kraskevich's solution doesn't have a copy constructor at all, as `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. While this is better than having a faulty copy constructor, you should try to stay more in line with the behavior of the standard library containers.

Also missing is a `size()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
class pointerArray
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> addresses; //<-- Use unique_ptr -> no delete function needed
public:
    pointerArray(size_t initialSize = 100) : //<-- use size_t
        addresses(initialSize)
    {}

    pointerArray(const pointerArray& other)  { //<-- implement deep copy
        addresses.resize(other.addresses.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < addresses.size(); ++i) {
            if (other.addresses[i] != nullptr) {
                addresses[i] = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(*other.addresses[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    pointerArray(pointerArray&& other) = default; //<-- default move constructor does exactly what it is supposed to do

    pointerArray& operator=(pointerArray other) { //<-- could be made minimally more efficent by implementing separate copy and move assigment operators
        addresses=std::move(other.addresses );
        return *this;
    }

    size_t size() { return addresses.size(); } //<-- handy when passed as a parameter

    T& operator[](size_t pos)   {
        if (pos >= addresses.size()) { //<-- compare against size, not capacity
            addresses.resize(pos+1);
        }
        if (addresses[pos] == nullptr) { //<-- compare against nullptr
            addresses[pos] = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
        }
        return *addresses[pos];
    }
};
```

Comment: naive question, but what happens if T does not implement a copy constructor and pointerArray<T> is created in this case?

Comment: Also, I'm not so sure the size function makes a lot of sense..  the data structure is addressable at any arbitrary index, and size() will return the size of the underlying vector, which is set to 2x the max pos requested, and should probably not be exposed since its internal behaviour...

Comment: Which brings to mind a new question, if someone accesses a[100000], and not enough memory is available to resize size, how should I fail gracefully ?

Comment: @Akash: As long as you don't try to copy `pointerArray`, nothing will happen. If you do you will - depending on your compiler - get a very long and ugly compiletime error message (as always, when templates are involved).

Comment: There are a lot of situations, where you need to know, how many elements are inside a container. But you are right with the `2x` growth. I corrected that in the answer. Its not necessary anyway, as the used `std::vector` usually already implements a quadratic growth algorithm.

Comment: @Akash: With this container structure you can't fail graicefully - you or the underlying `std::vector` have to throw an exception. But again, that is consitent with the behavior of the standard containers. A size of `100000` should not pose a problem anyway. If you want to fail gracefully, you have to e.g. return a pointer or `std::optinal` (not yet in the standard) and check on the calling side whether you actually got an object or not. Or you just don't implement automatic growth at all and use a separate growth function.